# Dynamodb create_table calls fails

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am following up Python tutorial for dynamodb setting local dynomodb on port 8000
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.01.html

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',  aws_access_key_id="anything", aws_secret_access_key="anything", region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")


table = dynamodb.create_table(
TableName='users',
KeySchema=[
    {
        'AttributeName': 'username',
        'KeyType': 'HASH'
    },
    {
        'AttributeName': 'last_name',
        'KeyType': 'RANGE'
    }
],
AttributeDefinitions=[
    {
        'AttributeName': 'username',
        'AttributeType': 'S'
    },
    {
        'AttributeName': 'last_name',
        'AttributeType': 'S'
    },

],
ProvisionedThroughput={
    'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
    'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
}

)
print("Table status:", table.table_status)
```

However python run to the code is failing with below issue.

Not sure what is causing it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rbharadw\workspace\dynamoDb\dynamoDb.py", line 32, in <module>
'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line  520, in do_action
response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\action.py", line 83, in __call__
response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 159, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 483, in _make_api_call
operation_model, request_dict)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 117, in make_request
return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 144, in _send_request
request, operation_model, attempts)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 203, in _get_response
response_dict, operation_model.output_shape)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 211, in parse
parsed = self._do_parse(response, shape)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 587, in _do_parse
parsed = self._parse_shape(shape, original_parsed)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 258, in _parse_shape
return handler(shape, node)
 File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 522, in _handle_structure
raw_value)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 258, in _parse_shape
return handler(shape, node)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 522, in _handle_structure
raw_value)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 258, in _parse_shape
return handler(shape, node)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 522, in _handle_structure
raw_value)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 258, in _parse_shape
return handler(shape, node)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 539, in _handle_timestamp
return self._timestamp_parser(value)
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 327, in parse_timestamp
return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value, tzlocal())
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\dateutil\tz\tz.py", line 99, in utcoffset
  if self._isdst(dt):
File "Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\dateutil\tz\tz.py", line 143, in    _isdst
return time.localtime(timestamp+time.timezone).tm_isdst
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

however it looks like tables get created as second run gives error for

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ResourceInUseException)  when calling the CreateTable operation: Cannot create preexisting table
```

Any suggestions!!!

Comment: It looks like you already have a table named ``users``.

Comment: Yes, second run is giving error for can-not create preexisting table.
however I am getting time specific error on first run that is the question

Comment: This looks like it is an issue between ``datetutils``, the Windows platform, and possibly a 32-bit version of Python.  This thread is relevant (https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/197) but doesn't seem to provide an easy answer but might help.

Comment: Actually I am having 64 bit version of python v3.5.2.

however yes changing time_zone UTC did help to work-around.

Comment: I am late to this but i faced a similar issue and took some time for me to resolve it. Here is my sample code for anyone who might need it: https://github.com/hardikvasa/database-journal/blob/master/code-samples/dynamodb.py

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately that set os.environ["TZ"] = "UTC" doesn't work for me.

So I follow one thread, locate the site-packages\dateutil\tz\tz.py file. In the def _naive_is_dst(self, dt) function, change it into

```
   # workaround the bug of negative offset UTC prob
    if timestamp+time.timezone < 0:
        current_time = timestamp + time.timezone + 31536000
    else:
        current_time = timestamp + time.timezone

    return time.localtime(current_time).tm_isdst
```

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a bug with one of the date processing libraries that boto uses.

The bug occurs when your timezone offset is a positive number.

You can work around it by inserting the following code before boto (or the library it uses) is imported.

```
import os
os.environ["TZ"] = "UTC"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me (Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.5.1, instead I did a work-around that if `timestamp+time.timezone < 0` I add 31536000 to it (difference between 1.1. 1970 and 1.1. 1971 in seconds). I hope it won't cause any bugs...

Comment: You are a hero. You saved me misery and tears

Comment: Is this an issue only for local instances of dynamoDB? I imagine since most DB are UTC already this isn't an issue there? Is that a correct assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the tz.py file, I decided to take Chen Wang's approach, but override the _naive_is_dst with my own implementation to leave tz.py untouched.

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    def _naive_is_dst(self, dt):
        timestamp = tz.tz._datetime_to_timestamp(dt)
        # workaround the bug of negative offset UTC prob
        if timestamp+time.timezone < 0:
            current_time = timestamp + time.timezone + 31536000
        else:
            current_time = timestamp + time.timezone
        return time.localtime(current_time).tm_isdst

tz.tzlocal._naive_is_dst = _naive_is_dst
```

Comment: I posted your solution in the [upstream issue](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/197#issuecomment-424426711). Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

```
def _naive_is_dst(self, dt):
    timestamp = _datetime_to_timestamp(dt)
    if timestamp+time.timezone < 0:
        current_time = timestamp + time.timezone + 31536000
    else:
        current_time = timestamp + time.timezone

    return time.localtime(current_time).tm_isdst
```